# Replace one <br /> with 2 regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a string...

```
$str = 'bob<br /><br />looked so good<br />tonight!';
```

I want to replace any instance where there is only one `<br />` with two.

At the moment I have...

```
echo preg_replace('/(<br \/>\s*){1}/', '<br /><br />', $str);
```

But this put's two `<br />` after bob when it should only go after good.

Any help would be great!

**Edit:** Output should be...

```
bob<br /><br />looked so good<br /><br />tonight!
```

Comment: Use the fifth parameter of the function -  the count, containing the matches...compare if the count is greater than 1 and...

Comment: So would `<br /><br /><br />` be left intact?

Comment: Do not use regex to manipulate HTML, because HTML is **not** a regular language. You'll eventually regret this. Use HTML libraries.

Comment: I'm not manipluating html forget it's that, I am trying to find 1 instance of a word and replace it with 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you want a `<br />` tag that is not preceded nor followed immediately by another. Thus:

```
/(?<!<br \/>)<br \/>(?!<br \/>)/
```

This assumes that all `<br />` tags are literally `<br />` and not `<br>`, `<br/>`, or even `<br style="clear:both;">`. for better parsing, you should use a DOM parser and look for `BR` nodes that are not preceded nor followed immediately by another `BR` node.

Answer (score 1):

This replaces any number (greater than zero) of `<br />` with two:

```
print preg_replace('|(?:<br />)+|', '<br /><br />', $str);
```

Example:

```
$str = 'bob<br /><br />looked so good<br />tonight!<br /><br /><br />Bye!';
print preg_replace('|(?:<br />)+|', '<br /><br />', $str);
# output: "bob<br /><br />looked so good<br /><br />tonight!<br /><br />Bye!"
```

Answer (score 0):

you're specifying that you want to match one 
 and replace it with two.

that's not what you want - you want to only add an extra 
 if that one is not followed by a second one of the same thing?

try

```
echo preg_replace('/(<br \/>\s*){1}([^<])/', '<br /><br />$1', $str);
```

this ensures that the 
 that you are matching is not followed by any other tag before replacing.

note that this wouldn't replace in the case of

```
<b>bob<br /></b>
```

though so you may want to be more specific with your ending boundary 
condition, as long as you ensure that you add it back to the end you can make the end boundary as complex as you like.